How can I make a text input control execute an action only when the user has finished typing and the control loses focus?
In Power Apps, how can I make a text input control execute an action, such as a search, only when the user has finished typing and the control loses focus? I've already selected "FocusOut" for the text input control's TriggerOutput property. According to Microsoft's documentation, TriggerOutput has three options:

FocusOut: Triggers OnChange only when the text input control loses focus. This is the default option.

Delayed: Triggers OnChange after a half-second delay. Useful for delaying expensive operations until the user completes inputting text.

Keypress: Triggers OnChange immediately as the user types.


Based on my understanding, "FocusOut" should be the behavior I want. However, even after selecting "FocusOut," the search is still being executed with every character typed (similar to the "Keypress" behavior), which significantly impacts performance.
Consider the following example: there is a text input control (inputEmail) and a label(resultName) control. After I input a user's email address into the text input, the label displays the user's name.
Here's my setting.
resultName.text = Office365Users.UserProfileV2(inputEmail.Value).displayName

The problem is that every time I type a letter into the text box, it throws the following error saying it can't be found(that's because I haven't input the whole email address yet.), until I finish typing the correct email address.

Office365Users.UserProfileV2 fail: { "error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "User not found", "innerError": xxxxxxxx} }

And the following setting also result the same issue:
Set OnChange property of inputEmail as
UpdateContext({resultName:Office365Users.UserProfileV2(inputEmail.Value).displayName})

Then set the Text property of Label
Text = resultName

How can I make it so that the search only starts when I finish typing the entire address / move my focus away from the text box?

I can't account for why your approach isn't working, but this works for me in getting the search to only be executed after the user exits focus. Intead of the way you have it, I use a variable attached to the onChange property, and then modify the display. I'm pretty certain this delays your search until the exit of the object so that should improve your performance.
Steps
For your TextBox set your onChange property to be something like this:
Set(searchTerm, TextSearchBox1.Text)

For your whatever you're searching against (presumably a gallery?), you can then update its Items formula to be something like:
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        [@zzzyourDataSourcezzz], 
        searchTerm in zzYourColumnName
    ), 
    "zzzString Of Search column", 
    If(SortDescending1, SortOrder.Descending, SortOrder.Ascending)
)

One other suggestion, if this doesn't work, you could use a good old button....
